# how set dynamically jsonld in vue 3 ssr

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, inertiajs, json-ld

When i try pass it by component is='script' type='application/ld+json' it has error:
"TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string", but when i pass it by teleport it works but only on client. I use  laravel inertiajs vue3 ssr

I tried to use v-html on component
`<component is='script' key='webSite' v-html='webSiteJSONLD' type='application/ld+json'></component>` but then it just insert data like attribute innerHTML in tag script.

in other way will be error: "TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string"
 `<component is='script' key='webSite' type='application/ld+json'>{{ webSiteJSONLD }}</component>`

text json
const webSiteJSONLD=computed(()=>{
return `{
'@context': 'https://schema.org',
'@type': 'WebSite',
'url': '${import.meta.env.SSR?import.meta.env.VITE_APP_URL:host.value}'
}`;
});

Comment: i found out that error "TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string" from Head component inertiajs  so i remove that component and i have no anymore that error but now json data encoded by htmlcode so it cant be read, also v-html now did no insert content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I writed fork head's component of inertia js and change function renderTag in component. And it works.But with bugs

```
renderTag(node) {
  // check specific symbol from node.type
  switch (node.type.toString()) {
    case 'Symbol(Text)':
    case 'Symbol(v-txt)':
      return node.children
    case 'Symbol()':
    case 'Symbol(Comment)':
      return ''
    // if nothing expected, return a html string
    default:
      return this.renderTagStart(node) + 
      (node.children ? this.renderTagChildren(node) : '') +
      (!this.isUnaryTag(node) ? `</${node.type}>` : '')
  }
}
```

Comment: Inertia updated and fix that issue. Right now need just no update inertia to 1.09

Answer (score 0):

Create a new component with :

```
mounted () {

    const myJsonScript = document.createElement('script');
    myJsonScript.setAttribute('type', 'application/ld+json');
    myJsonScript.setAttribute('src', '...src...');
    myJsonScript.setAttribute('id', 'random_id');
    document.getElementById('app').appendChild(myJsonScript)
}

beforeDestroy () {
    document.getElementById('random_id').remove()
}
```

Use props for each attributes, then it should be close to your need.

In pure SSR, you can do something like this in template:

```
{{{ "&lt;script type='application/ld+json' &gt;{'key': " + value + "}&lt;/script&gt;" }}}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. Unfortunately this not work for cuz i need render it on server, this solution will work on client (my opinion if i need do it on client i use use teleport) and by [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#reactivity-on-the-server) vue mount not working on ssr cuz dom did not changing . I use composition api. But found what in option api on ssr works  hook beforeCreate and create  i will try with them.

Comment: And document and window not exist on ssr.

Comment: I tried but the same error "TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string". Then i tried encodeURIComponent data  but get same error. But if i paste same data on client  all works fine.

Comment: And if it just a text i have no errors  but when it has {,:,} or other symbols i get error on renderTagStart(e) function